# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Uint8List>?'

Tags: flutter

> How to solve this error? Error message: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<Uint8List>?'.

[image]

My code

```
}

  Future<Uint8List> _getBlobData(html.Blob blob) {
    final completer = Completer<Uint8List>();
    final reader = html.FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    reader.onLoad.listen((_) => completer.complete(reader.result));
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`FileReader.result`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-html/FileReader/result.html) returns an `Object?` because it could return a `Uint8List`, a `String`, or `null`.  If you can guarantee that `reader.result` is a `Uint8List`, just perform a cast:

```dart
reader.onLoad.listen((_) => completer.complete(reader.result! as Uint8List));
```

Otherwise you should check the type of `reader.result` first.  For example:

```dart
reader.onLoad.listen((_) {
  var result = reader.result;
  if (result is Uint8List) {
    completer.complete(result);
  } else {
    completer.completeError(
      Exception('Unexpected result type: ${result.runtimeType}'));
  }
});
```